# Django HTTP post to same URL

Tags: json, django, http, post

What is the "proper" django way to do an HTTP POST to the same page when a button is clicked in that page?

I've got a django app which contains a page with two different buttons. Each button does a different thing but the results of the button press are returned in JSON format which then gets used to update the UI on the page.

I can obviously have each button submit to its own view and do it that way. But I can also make the page view respond to the button presses and detect whether the request is a POST or not.

Then there is the JSON mixin stuff - is it worth trying to use that somehow?

I've got it all working - I'd just like to know what the "proper" way to do it would be.

Any ideas?

Comment: A single Django view function can handle multiple Form objects. I usually just do a switch like `if "form-1-submit-button" in request.POST: form = Form1(request.POST) else form = Form2(request.POST)` but I am not sure if this is the best practice

Answer (score 0):

As Mikko Ohtamaa said, common practice is to check in your view which button was pressed. e.g.:

template.html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ obj_form.as_p }}
    <button name="action1" value="1" type="submit">
    <button name="action2" value="1" type="submit">
</form>
```

views.py:

```
if 'action1' in self.request.POST:
    form = Action1Form(request.POST)
elif 'action2' in self.request.POST:
    form = Action2Form(request.POST)
```

Using several forms in a single view is more convenient when you have one HTML form with different actions. If you have separate forms (or don't have them at all), I suggest using separate views for each action.

Comment: I'm not actually using forms - I'm just POSTing some info from the page whenever the user clicks one of the two buttons I have.

So you think I should use a separate view for each button action then?

Which do you think would be the most appropriate generic class-based view to use for that? Is it worth looking into using a JSON mixin maybe?

Comment: Best choice depends on what kind of processing you need. Mixins (as explained in [the JSONMixin example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html)) are used when you need to do same things in several views. If you don't have any reusable logic function-based views are completely fine to handle simple AJAX requests.